# Hello, I am using Eclipse to compile and run my java codes, but I am getting a error.(mac)

Tags: java

The error I am getting is below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: E: /Assignment1 /src/input (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at Stack.main(Stack.java:42)
```

My code:

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
           throws IOException {
        Stack s = new Stack(10);
        char ch;
    InputStreamReader r = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File("E: //Assignment1//src//input")));

        while ((ch = (char)r.read()) 
              != '\n')
           if (!s.full()) s.push(ch);
        r.close();
        while (!s.empty())
           System.out.print(s.pop());
        System.out.println();
```

My java project name Assignment1 and my text file name is input.
So what is wrong with this code format below:

```
 InputStreamReader r = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File("E: //Assignment1//src//input")));
```

Comment: remove the blank between E: and `//`. Ist there realy an drive `E` on a mac? MAC uses unix so i think there are no drive letters?!

Comment: You do not how to use / twice it something I did even with the space. I was trying something to see if it was going to fix the problem..But it did not change anything.

Comment: Ok I have got rid of the E and // but I am still receiving the same error message @Jens

Comment: @SammySmith What is the file do you want to read?

Comment: I think you have to specify the extension ...just only the junput name is not enough...if the input file is text the put input.txt and then check

Comment: Its a text file called input. The file is inside my project folder.. @Jens

Comment: @AbdulMuheet I  right click the file and went to get info (mac) it gave me the location of the file example Users ▸ *** ▸ Desktop. So, I type in that information and I still got the same error

Comment: And what is the path to your file?

Comment: I thought that my path file is Users ▸ *** ▸ Desktop @Jens

Comment: @SammySmith That is not a path. a path Looks like `/users/.../Decktop/...` in unix Format.

Comment: Sorry, I change it to "/Users/****/Desktop/Assignment1/src/input" @Jens

Comment: in window its working i maked it like this........InputStreamReader r = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File("E:\\HelloWorld.java")));

Comment: when i am removing the java extension then this giving me the filenotfound exception....

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse you should see, on the left hand side, a window "Package Explorer" showing your project. There should be a folder called `src`. Add a file to this folder, call it `input.txt` and type one line "abcdef" followed by carriage return (enter).

In your program, use this statement:

```
 InputStreamReader r =
     new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File("src/input.txt")));
```

(Using the directory `src` for storing data files is not ideal. You might try to create another folder below your project, a sibling to `src` and call it `resources`. Create your file there, and use `"resources/input.txt"` as the relative path name in your program.)